# How to delete item from ListView while using Custom ArrayAdapter w/ Dialog

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-arrayadapter

Some Context: I have a Custom ArrayAdapter for a ListView that has 3 parameters Name, Edit Button, Delete Button. I have setup `onClicks` in the ArrayAdapter to be able to detect which profile is being clicked with the specific edit/delete button press. When the user deletes a profile I remove the profile from `SQLite DB` however now I've ran into the problem of trying to update the `ArrayList` with the removed item and `notifyDataSetChanged` for my `ListView`.

Question 1: I can't figure out if I should be doing this in the Class that is containing the ListView and ArrayList or if I should be trying to update this from the ArrayAdapter in the onClicks.

Question 2: Whatever method might be right how can I correctly update the deleted item from the ListView when the user confirms the delete in the Dialog.

[image]

**Current ArrayAdapter Class**

```
public class ListViewItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem>
{
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ListViewItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private String profileName;

    public ListViewItemAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<ListViewItem> listItem) {
    super(context, 0 , listItem);
    mContext = context;
    list = listItem;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem = convertView;
    if(listItem == null)
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_listview,parent,false);

    final ListViewItem listViewItem = list.get(position);

    //Text View Profile
    final TextView name = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
    name.setText(listViewItem.getmName());
    profileName = listViewItem.getmName();

    //Edit Button Profile
    ImageButton image = listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView_poster);
    image.setImageResource(listViewItem.getmImageDrawable());
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,
                    "Edit Profile:" + listViewItem.getmProfile() + " Name:" + listViewItem.getmName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    //Delete Button Profile **Currently Testing**
    ImageButton image2 = listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView_poster2);
    image2.setImageResource(listViewItem.getmImageDrawable2());
    image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

            Toast.makeText(mContext,
                    "Delete Profile:" + listViewItem.getmProfile() + " Name:" + listViewItem.getmName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(),R.style.AlertDialogTheme);

            builder.setTitle("Delete Profile?")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete\n" + listViewItem.getmName())
                    .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            databaseHelper.deleteRowProfile(listViewItem.getmName());

                            //
                            //This is where I'm try to update the ListView
                            //

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    });


    return listItem;
}
}
```

**Function in Fragment Class that Populates the ListView onViewCreated**

```
public void getProfileList()
{
    arrayList = new ArrayList<ListViewItemAdapter>();
    listViewItemAdapter = new ListViewItemAdapter(getContext(),arrayList);

    Cursor result = databaseHelper.getAllDataCarProfile();

    if(listViewItemAdapter != null){
        listViewItemAdapter.clear();
        listViewItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    if (result.getCount() != 0)
    {
        while (result.moveToNext())
        {
            arrayList.add(new ListViewItem("CarProfile",
                    result.getString(0),
                    R.drawable.ic_edit_gray_24dp,
                    R.drawable.ic_delete_grey_24dp));
        }
        listViewItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    listViewCarProfile.setAdapter(listViewItemAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in either way . You can create a function in your adapter class and perform the clickListener on it .

```
deleteItem.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            potsList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

Or in your class , when remove the item from list , don't forget to notify the adapter . One the adapter get notified , it will reflect the change on screen.

Comment: Would this mean that I have to make the ArrayList accessible to the ArrayAdapter class or can this be accessed since technically its still in the context of the screen? If so how would I do that,  since right now that wont work since my ArrayList is not in the ArrayAdapter class

Comment: The working code was adding:  `list.remove(listViewItem);` then 
 `notifyDataSetChanged()`  as Mini Chip pointed out. Did not realize that the List in the ArrayAdapter takes attributes from my ArrayList in the Class. Thanks for the help!